# Google Calendar API returns 404 (not found) for different request

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, http-status-code-404, google-calendar-api

I implemented an app in .NET which synchronizes Google Calendar Events with my database events. It works fine until I need to use same Google API methods that need *eventId* as parameter, like *delete*, *move*, *update*. My problem is that this methods sometimes works, sometimes not. I can't figure out what's really the problem and in which situations the error is generated.
I also used [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and "Try this API" option on [Google Calendar API documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/) for testing with no success (still 404 error).

I have multiple calendars in Google, created by me and shared for me with full permisions. The problems appears with no logic, no matter if I'm the owner of the calendar or not.
The scopes that I'm using are: CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, CalendarService.Scope.CalendarEvents.

1. **Delete an event** from Google Calendar using my app.

   It gives me 404. Next, I tried to delete the same event on [Google Calendar API documentation - Events: delete](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete). Still 404. I verified if the event exist using [Google OAuth requests](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). Surprisingly it exists. Ok, let's try to delete it again. Same errors. If I don't lose my patience and try this enough, there comes a moment when everything works fine.
2. **Update an event**.

   Same problem: not found.
3. **Move an event** from one calendar to another.

   Same problem: not found. But in this situation I noticed a difference using [Google Calendar API documentation - Events: move](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/move) "Try this API" option: it doesn't work until I try to move an event from one of my calendar (owner) to another one of mine (owner). From this moment everything is working like it should with no other error (even with shared calendars).

**CalendarService.cs**

```
public CalendarService GetService()
{
    try
    {
         // Authenticated user credential
         var credential = GetUserCredential();
         if (credential == null)
             throw new ArgumentNullException("credential");

         // Create Calendar API service.
         return new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
         {
             HttpClientInitializer = credential,
             ApplicationName = ApplicationName
         });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         throw new Exception("Get Calendar service failed.", ex);
    }
}

private UserCredential GetUserCredential()
{
    try
    {
         UserCredential credential;

         using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
         {
             string credPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);

             // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
             // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
             credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    userId,
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)
                    ).Result;
          }
          credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
          return credential;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          throw new Exception("Get user credentials failed.", ex);
     }
}

public async Task MoveEvent(CalendarService service, string calendarId, string eventId, string destination)
{
    // Building the initial request & requesting data async
    await service.Events.Move(calendarId, eventId, destination).ExecuteAsync();
}
```

**CalendarLogic.cs**

```
private GoogleCalendarData calendarData = new GoogleCalendarData();
private GoogleCalendarService calendarService = new GoogleCalendarService();

public async Task MoveAppEvents(string sourceCalendarId, string destinationCalendarId)
{
    //Here events from database inserted in Google are retrieved
    var events = await calendarData.GetEvents(null, false);
    events.Where(item => item.GoogleEventId != "")
            .ToList()
            .ForEach((async item => await calendarService.MoveEvent(calendarService.GetService(), sourceCalendarId, item.GoogleEventId, destinationCalendarId)));
}
```

**CalendarController.cs**

```
private GoogleCalendarLogic googleCalendar = new GoogleCalendarLogic();

[Route("{calendarId}/appevents/move/{destination}")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task MoveAppEvents(string calendarId, string destination)
{
     await googleCalendar.MoveAppEvents(calendarId, destination);
}
```

Comment: How are you authorising your client, and are you connecting as yourself or a service account?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo As a user, using Oauth2 Authentication.

Comment: Can you post your auth code as well as your method calls?

Comment: I want to change the authentication method because I what to consume this API from an Angular app. But I'm not sure (yet) how exactly should I do this. Instead of GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync I should use GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow in the API (with the same logic) and the authentication/consent process should be handle in the Angular app. Is this the correct flow?